# Asp.NET Core, unable to find View of cshtml when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `RazorEngine` in my Asp.NET CORE service which generate dynamic html pages to be sent via EMAIL from a cshtml file that is stored in View folder..

The issue is that when the website is published the service is unable to find path to `Views/Emails/EmailRiepilogo.cshtml` as on publish the View folder is not even created...

So how can I reference to EmailRiepilogo.cshtml path when the service is published?

Here is how I'm reading the file:

```
string template = File.ReadAllText("Views/Emails/EmailRiepilogo.cshtml");
```

And here is the error:

Could not find a part of the path `'E:\VS2019\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\publish\Views\Emails\EmailRiepilogo.cshtml'.`

Should I just create static file as cshtml?

Comment: Does the file exist at that location? Check that it is being published and that your path is resolving to the correct fully qualified path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved by setting each cshtml files Compile Action to `Integrated Resource` and Copy to output directory to `Copy always` to in this way the View folder with it's cshtml files is being generated and the files are read properly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know where (in terms of folder structure in the host server) your application will be hosted. At the same time, methods like `File.ReadAllText` work best with absolute paths. You need to convert the relative path "Views/Emails/EmailRiepilogo.cshtml" to an absolute path. One way is to use `IHostingEnvironment` in Asp.Net Core (or `Server.MapPath` in Asp.Net). Just inject it to your service/controller and

```
string filename = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.ContentRootPath, "Views/Emails/EmailRiepilogo.cshtml");
string template = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

Of course, you need to check if the file exists where you expect after publishing the project.

Comment: Actually the main issue is that the file does exist only in debug mode, while compiled files `cshtml` with Views folder are not even generated

Answer (score 0):

I had excact same problem. Cshtml file Build action was somehow changed from Content -> None. It worked on local but not when published to server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).